# Image mask in css not working with local file

Tags: css, css-mask

I am trying to mask an image using CSS and the WebKit property ( -webkit-mask-image ) .
But due to some reason, the mask doesn't work when I use it from local files on my PC or even when I upload it to a website of mine and use the link. If I use the mask image directly from the tutorial website I followed the mask works fine. 
In the below code you can see I have commented out a webkit-mask-image and if you run the code as it is you would see nothing whereas if you uncomment it and comment out the second webkit-mask-image it would start working. Same thing happens if I use the file path of my PC instead of the tutorial URL. 
Please help me out with this. seems really weird.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>


    <style >
        html, body {
          height: 100%;
        }

        img.two {
          height: 50%;
          width: auto;
        }
        .mask4 {
          /*-webkit-mask-image: url("https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/d319533ac3d22c3186498254e0caee871796a29e/d7ce9/images/css/masking/image-mask.png");*/
          -webkit-mask-image: url("https://3dmetalart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/image-mask.png");
          -webkit-mask-size: 400px 600px;


        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Image mask using png </h1>
        <img class="two mask4"src="https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/175114938be87ad0c1170d95e2fdaa616846eb49/d40da/images/css/masking/masking-example1.jpg"><br>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394277/imgur-image-not-loading-due-to-cors-policy (it's a security issue)

Comment: @TemaniAfif   Turns out this is true, but how to solve it?

Comment: check configuration of your server or contact them